# How did find delta?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

From what I understand, to solve this I have to make |(x)^1/2 - 2| Of the epsilon inequality equal to the inequality expression involving delta. But I haven't figured out a way to do it.

Comment: The first step is to calculate the value of the two question marks in the figure. What are they?

Comment: Then you have to pick any $\delta$ so that $4\pm\delta$ is sure to lie between the two question marks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Solve $$\begin{cases}\sqrt{x_1} - 2 = 0.4 \\ 2 - \sqrt{x_2} = 0.4\end{cases}$$

Then $$\delta = \min\{ |x_1 - 4|, |x_2-4|\}$$

Comment: Is it $ \max\{ |x_1 - 4|, |x_2-4|\}$ or $ \min\{ |x_1 - 4|, |x_2-4|\}$?

Comment: @DavidK You are right sir. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x-4|<\delta\Rightarrow |\sqrt{x}-2|<0.4\\|\sqrt{x}-2|*\frac{|\sqrt{x}+2|}{|\sqrt{x}+2|}<0.4\\\frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt{x}+2|}<0.4\\then\\if (|x-4|<\delta)\\4-\delta<x<4+\delta\\ \sqrt{4-\delta}<\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{4+\delta}\\ \sqrt{4-\delta}+2<\sqrt{x}+2<\sqrt{4+\delta}+2\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+\delta}+2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-\delta}+2} \\
\frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt{x}+2|}<\frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt{4-\delta}+2|}<0.4\\|x-4|<0.4*|\sqrt{4-\delta}+2|\\usually\\max(\delta)=0.5\\so\\|x-4|<0.4*|\sqrt{4-0.5}+2|
$$

Comment: But $0.4 \cdot |\sqrt{4-0.5}+2| \approx 1.548$, and $\sqrt{4 - 0.4 \cdot|\sqrt{4-0.5}+2|} \approx 1.566 < 1.6.$

Answer (score 0):

While this looks somewhat like a step of a delta-epsilon continuity proof,
it's actually only asking for *one* value of $\delta.$
It's not even asking for the largest possible value of $\delta$ that satisfies
the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ inequality. Any $\delta$ will do as long as it
ensures that $1.6 < \sqrt{x} < 2.4.$

Here's a convenient observation: 
as long as it's a positive number, no value of $\delta$ is too *small*
to solve this problem.

This suggests a method for solving this problem that I would not recommend 
for a complete delta-epsilon proof: *guess a number*.

We even have a graph to make it easy. The graph looks like it's at least approximately
to scale, and the slope of $y = \sqrt{x}$ seems to be fairly shallow, 
certainly less than $1.$  And we only need the range of our function values
to fall within $2 \pm 0.4.$ 
So I'll make a wild guess and say $\delta = 0.1.$

Why $0.1?$ Why not?  The number $0.1$ is pretty small relative to the other
numbers in this problem but it's still easy to write.

But we need to check the answer, *especially* since this was just a guess.
OK, with $|x - 4| < \delta = 0.1,$ we have $3.9 < x < 4.1.$
You can just compute $\sqrt{3.9}$ and $\sqrt{4.1}$ on a calculator, and see
that the values are much closer to $2$ than they really need to be.
If you aren't supposed to use a calculator, observe that
$1.6^2 = 2.56$ and $2.4^2 = 5.76$ (easily calculated by hand)
and that $2.56 < 3.9 < x < 4.1 < 5.76,$ 
so $1.6 < \sqrt{3.9} < \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{4.1} < 2.4,$ as required.

From that last calculation, it's clear that I could have chosen a much larger
value of $\delta.$ In fact, $\delta = 1$ would have worked.
But so what? The problem asked only for *a* value of $\delta,$ not any special value.
We could have guessed $\delta = 0.01;$ it too would have worked.